# Javascript Error on Facebook Login using Chrome - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL. Domains, protocols and ports must match

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, google-chrome, facebook-c#-sdk

I have been running the facebook c# sdk successfully for a good year or more, and it stopped working early december.  This was due to the API changes at Facebook, and an informative error told me that i needed to use some new parameters in my calls (specifically `oAuth: true` )

I read up on the changes, and updated the sdk via nuget, which is now running on version 5.4.1.0 of [Facebook.JavascriptMvcWebsite](http://nuget.org/packages/Facebook.JavascriptMvcWebsite/5.4.1.0) and [FacebookWebMvc](http://nuget.org/packages/FacebookWebMvc/5.4.1.0) and the other required libraries that make up the [facebook c# sdk](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/).

Now, when clicking the facebook login button i get a different error...

**Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL** https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=251066398241630&skip_api_login=1&display=popup&cancel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%3Fversion%3D3%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%26error%3Daccess_denied%26error_description%3DThe%2Buser%2Bdenied%2Byour%2Brequest.%23cb%3Df3570617%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fgem.local%252Ffbb4f09e%26relation%3Dopener%26transport%3Dpostmessage%26frame%3Df1c822218c&fbconnect=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Fpermissions.request%3F_path%3Dpermissions.request%26app_id%3D251066398241630%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fs-static.ak.fbcdn.net%252Fconnect%252Fxd_proxy.php%253Fversion%253D3%2523cb%253Df3570617%2526origin%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fgem.local%25252Ffbb4f09e%2526relation%253Dopener%2526transport%253Dpostmessage%2526frame%253Df1c822218c%26sdk%3Djoey%26display%3Dpopup%26response_type%3Dtoken%252Csigned_request%26fbconnect%3D1%26from_login%3D1&rcount=1 from frame with URL http://gem.local/Account/LogOn. **Domains, protocols and ports must match.**

The console window in Chrome then racks up about 5 of these errors a second, all coming from the facebook login dialog.

I have tried modifying the fbChannel.ashx file to explicity use http:// instead of just // (which respects the current protocol) and also have done the same in FacebookInit.cshtml, but none of this is making any difference.

I also modified my facebook app settings to allow deprecated code...
[image]

What am i missing here?  I understand why the browser is having a fit over cross domain access, but what is causing this?  Have facebook completely switched to https?  can i still use facebook logins over http?

I have a [test site up where you can see the error in action](http://test.sk8loc8.com/Account/LogOn)

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the App Domain Field (leave it blank) in Facebook Application --> Basic Info